# How to make a new line associated to the same equation inside subnumcases?

Tags: cross-referencing, line-breaking, labels, cases

I would like to write a new line associated to the same equation inside a `subnumcases` environment, as the whole equation is too big to fit into a single line. For that purpose, I tried to use the `\\` command to create the new line, writing the following code (see the equation associated to the second label `\label{eq:T_trh_rot_equation_1D_implementation}`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{cases}    

\begin{document}

\begin{subnumcases}{}
\frac{d c_{s,e,v}}{d x}=\frac{\dot{\omega}_{s,e,v}}{\rho u},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall s,\,e\,\text{and }v\text{ ,}
\label{eq:mass_equation_ve_1D_final_implementation}
\\
\frac{d T_{\text{tr}_\text{h}}}{dx}+\frac{\left(\sum_{s\in\{\text{h}\}} c_s\right)u}{\sum_{s\in\{\text{h}\}}c_sC_{p,s,\text{tr-rot}}}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}=\\
=-\frac{\dot{\Omega}_{\text{rad}}+\left(\sum_s\dot{\Omega}_{s,\text{e}}^{\text{int}}\right)+\left[\sum_{s\in\{\text{h}\}}\dot{\omega}_s\left(h_s+\frac{1}{2}u^2\right)\right]+\left[\sum_{s\in\{\text{h}\},e,v}\left(\dot{\omega}_{s,e,v}-\frac{c_{s,e,v}}{c_s}\dot{\omega}_s\right)\frac{\epsilon_{s,\text{el-vib},e,v}}{m_s}\right]}{\rho u\left(\sum_{s\in\{\text{h}\}}c_sC_{p,s,\text{tr-rot}}\right)}\text{ ,}
\label{eq:T_trh_rot_equation_1D_implementation}
\\
\frac{d T_{\text{tr}_\text{e}}}{d x}+\frac{u}{C_{p,\text{e}}}\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{\left(\sum_s\dot{\Omega}_{s,\text{e}}^{\text{int}}\right)-\dot{\omega}_\text{e}\left(h_\text{e}+\frac{1}{2}u^2\right)}{\rho u c_\text{e}C_{p,\text{e}}}\text{ .}
\label{eq:T_tre_equation_1D_implementation}
\end{subnumcases}

\end{document}
```

This results in:
[image]
Two reference numbers, (1b) and (1c), are assigned to the two lines since the `subnumcases` environment uses this command to separate equations. I just want one label (i.e. the current (1c) which should be changed to "(1b)" due to the supressing of the previous (1b)), since it corresponds to a single equation. Is there any command to make a new line for the same equation giving it a single label?

Comment: There are many `\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,` in your code. You can use also `\quad` or `\qquad`.

Comment: You're right. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out a way of writing an equation divided into two lines inside the `subnumcases` environment, and giving it a single label. It required the use of the `\parbox` command which allows the `\\` command to be inserted without creating a new equation. The length of the box was defined as the one associated to the second line (since it is the biggest of the two) by using the `\widthof` command (of the `calc` package), which computes it. The new code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{cases}    
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{subnumcases}{}
\frac{d c_{s,e,v}}{d x}=\frac{\dot{\omega}_{s,e,v}}{\rho u},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall s,\,e\,\text{and }v\text{ ,}
\label{eq:mass_equation_ve_1D_final_implementation}
\\
\parbox{
\widthof{$
\displaystyle
=-\frac{\dot{\Omega}_{\text{rad}}+\left(\sum_s\dot{\Omega}_{s,\text{e}}^{\text{int}}\right)+\left[\sum_{s\in\{\text{h}\}}\dot{\omega}_s\left(h_s+\frac{1}{2}u^2\right)\right]+\left[\sum_{s\in\{\text{h}\},e,v}\left(\dot{\omega}_{s,e,v}-\frac{c_{s,e,v}}{c_s}\dot{\omega}_s\right)\frac{\epsilon_{s,\text{el-vib},e,v}}{m_s}\right]}{\rho u\left(\sum_{s\in\{\text{h}\}}c_sC_{p,s,\text{tr-rot}}\right)}\text{ ,}
$}}
{$
\displaystyle
\frac{d T_{\text{tr}_\text{h}}}{dx}+\frac{\left(\sum_{s\in\{\text{h}\}} c_s\right)u}{\sum_{s\in\{\text{h}\}}c_sC_{p,s,\text{tr-rot}}}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}=\\
=-\frac{\dot{\Omega}_{\text{rad}}+\left(\sum_s\dot{\Omega}_{s,\text{e}}^{\text{int}}\right)+\left[\sum_{s\in\{\text{h}\}}\dot{\omega}_s\left(h_s+\frac{1}{2}u^2\right)\right]+\left[\sum_{s\in\{\text{h}\},e,v}\left(\dot{\omega}_{s,e,v}-\frac{c_{s,e,v}}{c_s}\dot{\omega}_s\right)\frac{\epsilon_{s,\text{el-vib},e,v}}{m_s}\right]}{\rho u\left(\sum_{s\in\{\text{h}\}}c_sC_{p,s,\text{tr-rot}}\right)}\text{ ,}
$}
\label{eq:T_trh_rot_equation_1D_implementation}
\\
\frac{d T_{\text{tr}_\text{e}}}{d x}+\frac{u}{C_{p,\text{e}}}\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{\left(\sum_s\dot{\Omega}_{s,\text{e}}^{\text{int}}\right)-\dot{\omega}_\text{e}\left(h_\text{e}+\frac{1}{2}u^2\right)}{\rho u c_\text{e}C_{p,\text{e}}}\text{ .}
\label{eq:T_tre_equation_1D_implementation}
\end{subnumcases}

\end{document}
```

which results in
[image]